# How to ignore rows whose numbers are more than 6 digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few codes as you see in the screenshot below.

I want my database only to take code that has exactly 6 digits. The code which has more than 6 digits is expected to be deleted/ignored.

How do I write my SQL query for the same?

[image]

I was thinking to use Patindex but couldn't succeed in it.

Comment: `where len([Code]) = 6`

Comment: What is the type of the data in that column?

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: @jarlh its of int type

Comment: If it's int, simply do `where code >= 1000000` to get _more_ than 6 digit numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Code LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```